# How to add a space before and after certain characters using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I know that I can add space after or before a character using

```
sed -i 's/char/char /g' fname.txt
```

However, I need help adding space before and after these characters ```[]<>'''

for example,

```
nie[breath]hi
hi </langenglish>'tjie
```

would turn into

```
nie [breath] hi
hi </langenglish> 'tjie
```

NOTE: that i want a single space after `<>[]` because using the first code, I would essentially get two spaces.

Please let me know how I could accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example it seems like you're mis-specifying your problem and you actually want a space before and after every `[...]` or `<...>` string rather than before and after every `[`, `]`, `<`, or `>` character. If that's correct then using any sed that allows `\n` to represent a newline in the regexp and replacement text (e.g. GNU sed):

```
$ sed 's/ /\n/g; s/\[[^]]*]/ & /g; s/<[^>]*>/ & /g; s/ *\n */ /g' file
nie [breath] hi
hi </langenglish> 'tjie
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1' file
nie [breath] hi
hi </langenglish> 'tjie
```

You should add some non-sunny-day test cases to your example to make sure you get what you really need, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'head[foo<bar]tail' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1'
head [foo<bar] tail

$ echo 'head<foo<bar>tail' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1'
head <foo<bar> tail

$ echo 'head<foo[bar>tail' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1'
head <foo[bar> tail

$ echo 'head<foo]bar>tail' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1'
head <foo]bar> tail

$ echo 'head<foo[bar]tail' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n"); gsub(/\[[^]]*]/," & "); gsub(/<[^>]*>/," & "); gsub(/ *\n */," ")} 1'
head<foo [bar] tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Written as per shown samples only. This will add spaces before `[` and `<` then it will add spaces after `>` and `]`. As per shown samples.

```
awk '{gsub(/\[|</," &");gsub(/\]|>/,"& ")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simply globally substituting `[` and `>` with spaces before their values in first `gsub`. Then performing second global substitution to add spaces after `>` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([]>]\)[[:space:]]*/\1 /g;s/[[:space:]]*\([[<]\)[[:space:]]*/ \1/g' file > newfile
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/4lUdum):

```sh
s="nie[breath]hi
hi </langenglish>'tjie"
sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([]>]\)[[:space:]]*/\1 /g;s/[[:space:]]*\([[<]\)[[:space:]]*/ \1/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
nie [breath] hi
hi </langenglish> 'tjie
```

Details:

- `s/[[:space:]]*\([]>]\)[[:space:]]*/\1 /g`  - "normalizes" whitespace before `]` and `>` chars by removing all whitespace before and keeping one after
- `s/[[:space:]]*\([[<]\)[[:space:]]*/ \1/g`  - "normalizes" whitespace before `[` and `<` chars by removing all whitespace after and keeping one before